# Crop picture right after taken in windows phone 8 development

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, camera, capture

I am creating app that allow user to use pictures from photo hub & take new photo to edit

I know that I can take picture from PhotoChoserTask but I want 2 seperate things.

Now I need to crop taken picture right after capture (like what I can do with PhotoChoserTask)

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CameraCaptureTask doesn't have Height and Width properties, so you cannot crop the image right after it is taken.
You can do two things:

1 - (I don't prefer this one!) Allow the user to take a picture using the CamerCaptureTask and then after it is completed, call the PhotoChoserTask so that the user again chooses the clicked image. Using this option you can crop the image using the Height and Width properties of the PhotoChoserTask

2 - Use Nokia Imaging SDK to crop the image. This SDK has many filters including the Crop filter which can be used to crop images. It is not as easy the PhotoChoserTask crop but you can still crop the image. There is sample code to crop an image on this [page](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Imaging_API_Ref/nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/cropfilter-class.html). Check it out!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using Nokia Imaging SDK for my app might be a little bit too much (I don't need all the filter in the SDK and including the SDK in my project will make the size of app increase)
But it seems that it's the only choice here. Thanks

Comment: The dll is of very little size. I don't think you have to worry about the size when using the imaging SDK. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Same as PhotoChoserTask, CameraCapturTask also has 'completed' event. Both are same so you can apply the same code of PhotoChoserTask 'completed' event to CameraCaptureTask 'completed' event. Use 'e.ChosenPhoto' argument property to get the stream of captured image.

Comment: In PhotochoserTask we can define pixelHeight & pixelWidth, so after chosen the photo, user will need to crop with the resolution we gave. Unfortunately, CameraCaptureTask doesn't have pixelHeight & pixelWidth properties. So I wonder how can I crop image after taken